# Call a function in every controller

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, extensions, controllers

I have controller file called Authorize.php, in this file i have check either the user is allowed to make request and i have other controller files like products.php and etc, i would like to call Authorize.php file in products.php or want to call Authorize function in my other controller files.

I would like to know, what will be the way to do so.

Comment: I think best way is to define your method into helper class and call it into your controller or where you need it [ref](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-helpers-in-magento-2/)

Comment: you can check it with either `predispatch` or `postdispatch` method availabe for any controller